# Sharepoint 2010 updates which one to install KB4032221 or KB4032215

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update, patching

I have a SharePoint 2010 farm and want to install the latest cumulative updates  which updates should be installed, here I found two links

[August 14, 2018, cumulative update for SharePoint Server 2010 (KB4032221)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032221/august-14-2018-cumulative-update-for-sharepoint-server-2010-kb4032221)

Security Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB4032215)

[Description of the security update for SharePoint Server 2010: August 14, 2018](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4032215/description-of-the-security-update-for-sharepoint-server-2010-august)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, The first one that refers to the CU,

> The **CU** already include the `security update`.

It's also preferred to download the `Full Server Packages` for Aug 2018 from [Update for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB4032221)](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2018/08/14/august-2018-cu-for-sharepoint-2010-product-family-is-available-for-download/) that include all security update since Service Pack 2.

---

**Note:**

- It’s not recommended to install SharePoint update on production environment until tested on dev/test environment.
- As a prerequisite, the Aug 2018 update requires SharePoint 2010 Service pack 2 to be installed
- Perform a full backup before starting the update process because you can’t rollback the Cumulative Update Installation.
- It’s recommended to install the CU that will solve a specific issue in your farm, by checking the improvements and issues that should be fixed before applying the cumulative update.
- The update process requires downtime, so you should schedule a new RFC with an outage to apply a new patch.
- After installing, Don't forget to run the configuration wizard to apply the patch.

For more details, check [FIND FARM PATCH LEVEL / LATEST CUMULATIVE UPDATE THAT HAS BEEN INSTALLED ON SHAREPOINT FARM](https://blog.devoworx.net/2014/11/30/find-latest-cumulative-update-installed-in-sharepoint-farm/)